# Connect Kinect app to Kinect Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect, kinect-sdk

I am building a Kinect app with the Kinect SDK version 1.6.  I would like to record a .xed file with Kinect Studio and then use that .xed file to test my app without having to connect a Kinect sensor every time.

I have recorded the .xed file successfully and I am now trying to run my app using the .xed file as input instead of a sensor.  The problem is that when my app first loads, it checks for connected sensors and connects to one if it exists - if one doesn't exist it can't connect and must exit.  However, my app must be running when Kinect Studio loads in order for Studio to connect to a running Kinect app.  So my question is - what is the design pattern?

Should the app start running and wait for an active sensor, then connect?  Or should Studio be running and waiting for a Kinect app to start, and then connect itself to the app?  All of the examples given by Microsoft just check once for connected devices and then exit if one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an event handler for when the Kinect Sensor state changes:

```
KinectSensor.KinectSensors.StatusChanged += Kinect_StatusChanged;
```

Then, when the status changes and the Sensor is connected, you can initialise your sensor as you were normally doing at startup:

```
void Kinect_StatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Status)
    {
        case KinectStatus.Connected:
            if (kinectSensor == null)
            {
                kinectSensor = e.Sensor;
                Initialize();
            }
            break;
        case KinectStatus.Disconnected:
            if (kinectSensor == e.Sensor)
            {
                Clean();
                // Notify user, change state of APP appropriately
            }
            break;
        case KinectStatus.NotReady:
            break;
        case KinectStatus.NotPowered:
            if (kinectSensor == e.Sensor)
            {
                Clean();
                // Notify user, change state of APP appropriately
            }
            break;
        default:
            // Throw exception, notify user or ignore depending on use case
            break;
    }
}
```

---

So in summary, the pattern I use at startup is:

1. Subscribe to the StatusChanged event
2. Try to initialise the Kinect Sensor

Then when the state of the Kinect Sensor changes, my app can react appropriately.

Note, this type of pattern should apply to all applications not just this specific use case.  All Kinect enabled apps should react approriately it the Kinect Sensor is disconnected.

Comment: awesome, thanks a lot!  I will have a chance to implement this in the next few days, I'll post if I have any problems